# How to parse this XML using PHP?

Tags: php, simplexml

I would like to do parse XML for the url:
http://www.opencellid.org/cell/get?key=myapikey&mcc=250&mnc=99&cellid=29513&lac=0

I am the beginner of PHP and tried the code as below:

$url = "http://www.opencellid.org/cell/get?key=myapikey&mcc=250&mnc=99&cellid=29513&lac=0";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("feed not loading");

print_r($xml);

var_dump($xml);

I would like to do echo for each attribute e.g. lat, lon, range.. for this XML url.

I found many resource in stackoverflow which the XML is quite standard. I cannot find an example which is used for this format of XML:

Anyone could give me an idea? Thanks.

Comment: Use @Praveen kalal answers if you want a shorter code, but if you are concern with speed, use curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = "http://www.opencellid.org/cell/get?key=myapikey&mcc=250&mnc=99&cellid=29513&lac=0";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if($status==200){
    $x = new SimpleXMLElement($data,LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    echo 'lat: '.$x->cell['lat'];
    echo 'lon: '.$x->cell['lon'];
    echo 'range: '.$x->cell['range'];
}
```

**Update:** 
This is an alternative to curl. If you have curl installed, use curl, it is faster.

```
$url = "http://www.opencellid.org/cell/get?key=myapikey&mcc=250&mnc=99&cellid=29513&lac=0";

$data = file_get_contents($url);
$x = new SimpleXMLElement($data,LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$lat = $x->cell['lat'];
$lng = $x->cell['lon'];
$range = $x->cell['range'];

echo 'lat: '.$lat.'<br>';
echo 'lng: '.$lng.'<br>';
echo 'range: '.$range.'<br>';
```

Comment: Thanks but it gots the message "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init()".

Comment: I think the webserver didn't install the extension=php_curl.dll.

Comment: then, use file_get_contents($url), and remove the if($status==200)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
 $content = file_get_contents('http://www.opencellid.org/cell/get?key=myapikey&mcc=250&mnc=99&cellid=29513&lac=0');  
 $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);  

foreach($x->cell as $entry) {  
         echo $entry['lat']."==".$entry['lon']; exit;
        }
```

Comment: THanks for your help. How can I get the attributes e.g. lat, lon, range? How can I do echo to check for each attributes? Thanks.

Comment: I prefer this answer echo 'lat: '.$x->cell['lat'];
    echo 'lon: '.$x->cell['lon'];
    echo 'range: '.$x->cell['range'];

Answer (score 0):

$url = "http://www.opencellid.org/cell/get?key=myapikey&mcc=250&mnc=99&cellid=29513&lac=0";

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("feed not loading");

$attr = array("lat", "lon"); //list attr you require

foreach($xml->cell as $cell){
    $data = $cell->attributes();

foreach ($attr as $key) {
//         echo "<br>key: $key, value: " . $data[$key];
//edit to insert
$columns[] = $key; 
$values[] = $data[$key];
}

echo $query = "insert into table_name(".implode(',',$columns).") values     (".implode(',',$values).")";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Angelin, How can I get the attribute e.g. lat individually? Eventually the attribute will be uploaded to mysql. So I should figure out how to extract for each attribute! <br>lac:0<br>mcc:250<br>lat:50.5715642160311<br>cellId:29513<br>lon:25.2897075399231<br>nbSamples:57<br>mnc:99<br>range:6000

Comment: Hi How can I put those attribute from the URL to table of MySQL?

Comment: I think, the problem was in parsing, i misplaced the string in the make of the query, "insert into table_name("..... (".implode(',',$values)...